# Unity Shader Graph transparency not displayed correctly in-game

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, shader-graph

I created a simple heat distortion shader graph in Unity. In Shader Graph preview it looks fine:
[image]

But when I tried to use it in scene, it seems to be messed up: [image]

Instead of using alpha value from shader, the sprite is simply clipped to the Outline parameter  from the import settings. Here is the shader graph itself:
[image]

I'm using URP, Unity 2021. What am I doing wrong?